# Fold all comment blocks on file open vscode. Run a command or task on file open

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm looking for a way to fold all of the multi line comments when I open a file in the editor.

I.e. is there a way to execute a command ("editor.foldAllBlockComments") on a file when it gets opened?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible yet, but there is an issue asking for the ability to run a task on file open/focus and that could be used to solve your issue.  It is a backlog candidate so it needs your vote.

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/88471 [Auto run task on file open/focus #88471]